# Работа с API сайта https://www.weatherbit.io/api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

Нужно вывести текущие данные о погоде с использованием API сайта https://www.weatherbit.io/api

Данные о погоде должны быть выведены в текстовом виде.

```
# import required modules
import requests, json

# Enter your API key here
api_key = "API_key"

# base_url variable to store url
base_url = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?"
# Give city name
city_name = input("Enter city name : ")

# complete_url variable to store
# complete url address
complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name

# get method of requests module
# return response object
response = requests.get(complete_url)

# json method of response object
# convert json format data into
# python format data
x = response.json()


# store the value corresponding
# to the "temp" key of y
current_temperature = ["temp"]

# store the value corresponding
# to the "pressure" key of y
current_pressure = ["pres"]

# store the value corresponding
# to the "humidity" key of y
current_humidity = ["rh"]

# store the value of "weather"
# key in variable z
z = ["weather"]

# store the value corresponding
# to the "description" key at
# the 0th index of z
weather_description = ["description"]

# print following values
print(" Temperature (in kelvin unit) = " +
      str(current_temperature) +
      "\n atmospheric pressure (in hPa unit) = " +
      str(current_pressure) +
      "\n humidity (in percentage) = " +
      str(current_humidity) +
      "\n description = " +
      str(weather_description))
```

Но результат выходит пустой без температурных значений:

```
Enter city name : Moscow
 Temperature (in kelvin unit) = ['temp']
 atmospheric pressure (in hPa unit) = ['pres']
 humidity (in percentage) = ['rh']
 description = ['description']
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны изучить как указать индексы json данных.
Рекомендую посмотреть: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQfNYqz8pLs .
Я сделала так:

```
json_data = requests.get(url).json()
series = json_data['data'] 
for i in series:
   print(i)
```

Далее, отдельно выбираете, что вам нужно.Например температура:

```
series2 = i['temp']
print("Температура: "+ str(series2) + 'ºC')
```

Результат выглядить так: `Температура: 11ºC`